# How to resize/change y-axis scale in spatial plot raster to remove white area

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, raster, axis

I have this raster (image below) that I would like to resize as there is excess area below and above the continents (on the y-axis).

global land cover raster
[image: 1]

Comment: You just need to resize the canvas before your plot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to trim white space and fix coordinates, the following `expand` argument may help:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_map(
    data = map_data("world"), map = map_data("world"),
    aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = region)
  ) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image: world map]